# User properties vs users properties

Tags: plural-forms, compounds

If I had a file with the properties (names, ages and the like) of the users of some app, which one sentence would be correct to say "I have a file with the user properties" or "I have a file with the users properties"? I'm not sure that using the "noun as adjective" in the plural form is correct, but when I say "user properties" it sounds like I mean I have a file with a list of names of properties. Maybe is there another way to say it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say "user properties". They are the properties that apply to a user. "User" here is a noun being used as an adjective.

If you say "users properties", it would mean the same thing. I just think "user properties" is the more common thing for people to say.

Whether the file contains just the names of properties or values for those properties, neither term you suggest would specify. If someone told me he had a file of "user properties" or "users properties", with no further context or explanation, I'd most likely assume he meant values and not names. But you could use exactly the same words in a context where you were talking about lists of property names, so, etc.

If there is potential ambiguity and you want to make it clear, you'd have to add some additional words. Like, "This file contains the names of the user properties" or "This file contains the user properties, with the values for each user". I don't know of any 1 or 2 word name you could give that would make such a distinction clear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use "user data", or "attributes of users".